# Angular-Cli Build with Proxy file on AWS

Tags: proxy, angular-cli

I am trying to build Angular Build With Proxy file i can serve with proxy file but proxy not working with Angular build

```
 [{
    "context": ["/api1", "/api2"],
    "target": "http://api.expamle.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
 }]
```

api should work When i make Build i got CORS error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Docker image to deploy your code you need to add http-proxy-middleware into your package.json file and add below code into your index.js or any other file your running you command.

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')
var apiProxy = proxy('/api', {target: 'http://www.example.org/api'});
app.use(apiProxy)
```